# What is the finite-difference representation of the Laplacian operator with periodic boundary conditions?

Tags: finite-difference, boundary-conditions, laplacian

I am using a central-difference scheme to solve the eigenvalue problem

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}u = \lambda u$$

on a unit interval with periodic boundary conditions. My understanding is the eigenvectors $u_i$ have the analytic form

$$u_i(x) = e^{in\pi x}$$

I know that, for example, with dirichlet boundary conditions $u_0 = u_{N+1} = 0$ and $N = 6$, the central-difference representation of the Laplacian is

$$
\frac{1}{h^2}\begin{bmatrix}
    2       & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    -1       & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 2 & -1 &  0 & 0\\
    0 &0 & -1 & 2 & -1 &  0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
But I'm not sure about with periodic boundary conditions. My best guess so far is

$$
\frac{1}{h^2}\begin{bmatrix}
    2       & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
    -1       & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 2 & -1 &  0 & 0\\
    0 &0 & -1 & 2 & -1 &  0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
    -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

But this doesn't give me the expected eigenvectors.

My question: Is my form above correct?

Comment: Your anti-diagonal entries for BCs should be $1$s not $-1$s. Does this [question/answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/10834/20688) solves your issues?